# Creating checkboxes dynamically with an array of checkboxnames

Tags: reactjs

For my project I am trying to loop through an array in order to create checkboxes dynamically, but I am doing a silly mistake and cant seem to use my function... Im sure i am syntactically wrong, but I can't seem to find the resource for correcting my mistake. What am I doing wrong?

My function

```
   createBoxes(boxArray) {
        const checkboxArray = []
        for(var i = 0; i < boxArray; i++){
           checkboxArray.push(<Checkbox
                key={i}
                className="madeBoxes"
                endpointValue={this.state.endpointValue}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                handleCheck={this.handleCheck}
                label={labels[i]}
                />)
                console.log(checkboxArray)
    }
    return checkboxArray
}
```

My render function down to the point of function entry

```
render() {
        return (
        <div className="search_content">
        <div className="search_wrapper">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="#">
        <label>
                <input type="text" className="search_bar" value={this.state.searchValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </label>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" className="search_button" value="May the Force be with you." onClick={() =>  this.props.searchWithApi(APIQuery + this.state.endpointValue + this.state.searchValue)}/>
            </div>
        </form> 

        </div>

         <div className="checkboxes">  
         {this.createBoxes(this.labels)}
```

Comment: can you share the code where you are rendering the checkbox array?

Comment: Instead of creating an array of <CheckBox> I suggest you to map your array (boxArray) in the render method. Simply, {this.labels.map(box => {...})} instead of your last line, where in place of ... you put the <Checkbox> element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing `this.labels` into `createBoxes` as the value for `boxArray`, but then referencing `labels[i]` in the function. Should this instead be `boxArray[i]`? 
Also, your for loop should be `for(var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++)` if `boxArray` is going to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

After forgetting about this SO I eventually came to a conclusion. I changed the way they were being created.

```
createBoxes() {
const checkboxArray = [];
searchLabels.map(item => checkboxArray.push(
  <Checkbox
    key={item}
    className="madeBoxes"
    subKey={item}
    endpointValue={this.state.endpointValue}
    handleChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
    handleCheck={e => this.handleCheck(e)}
    label={item}
  />,
));
return checkboxArray;
```

}